# asp validation controls not firing after ajaxrequest been called

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, validation, telerik

`Asp` validation controls not firing after `ajaxrequest` been called.

I'm calling a function with below code to refresh a grid.

```
window['My Grid Client ID'].AjaxRequest('My Grid Unique ID', 'Rebind');
```

after `Grid` refreshed, validation not firing on `click` of submit button for the first time. for the next click it is working fine.

Hope this is due to `ajax` problem.!!

please respond if any one came across this scenario...

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned you are using `Telerik`. I would suggest you to `rebind` grid using below code instead of `AjaxRequest`, this will `Rebind` grid from `ClientSide`.

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshGrid() {
        var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>");
        var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
        masterTableView.fireCommand("Rebind");
    }
</script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

For more help on this you could use below links

- [RadGrid Client side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-familiar-with-client-side-api.html)
- [RadGrid Client object](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-getting-client-object.html)

This will not use any `AjaxRequest` to bind grid and will not affect any of your `Validation` functionality.

Hope this helps..!!!

Answer (score 0):

What validation are you using? If it is custom validation and your JavaScript code is in the user control you load with the ajax request, this script will not actually exist in the browser. Wrap it in a RadScriptBlock control or use the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method to have it working on the page.

Also, make sure you have proper ValidationGroup settings for all your validators. If some submit buttons appear with AJAX this may break your existing page if you have no groups defined.